# (Unity) AdMob Problem RealAds not Showing

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, admob, ads

-EDIT- Can it be because of GPGS(Google Play Game Services)??? 
I have imported the Admob Unity SDK and configured it successfully with Test ads.
Everything works fine with test ads, but when I put my real ads strings even if I use `AddTestDevice(SystemInfo.deviceUniqueIdentifier)` nothing happens.

I made another project to test the same real ads and the ads are shown ok.

So the problem is: real ads are shown fine in other projects but in the main project nothing happens, even if test ads work correctly.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

using GoogleMobileAds;
using GoogleMobileAds.Api;
using System;

public class AdManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    private RewardedAd rewardedAd;
    private BannerView bannerView;
    public InterstitialAd interstitial;

    private void RequestInterstitial()
    {
#if UNITY_ANDROID
        string adUnitId = "ca-app-pub-2993038425431208/1298871084";

#elif UNITY_IPHONE
        string adUnitId = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/4411468910";
#else
        string adUnitId = "unexpected_platform";
#endif


        this.interstitial = new InterstitialAd(adUnitId);       
        AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder().AddTestDevice(SystemInfo.deviceUniqueIdentifier).Build();      
        this.interstitial.LoadAd(request);
    }
    string appId;
    public void Start()
    {

#if UNITY_ANDROID
         appId = "ca-app-pub-2993038425431208~5325638202";
#elif UNITY_IPHONE
             appId = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~1458002511";
#else
             appId = "unexpected_platform";
#endif
        //AdRequest.Builder.addbcx("33BE2250B43518CCDA7DE426D04EE231");

        MobileAds.Initialize(appId);
        this.RequestBanner();
        this.RequestInterstitial();     
        this.LoadReward();
    }

    private void LoadReward()
    {
        string adUnitId;
#if UNITY_ANDROID
        adUnitId = "ca-app-pub-2993038425431208/2201384054";        
#elif UNITY_IPHONE
            adUnitId = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1712485313";
#else
            adUnitId = "unexpected_platform";
#endif

        this.rewardedAd = new RewardedAd(adUnitId);
        this.rewardedAd.OnAdLoaded += HandleRewardedAdLoaded;       
        this.rewardedAd.OnAdFailedToLoad += HandleRewardedAdFailedToLoad;       
        this.rewardedAd.OnAdOpening += HandleRewardedAdOpening;       
        this.rewardedAd.OnAdFailedToShow += HandleRewardedAdFailedToShow;
        this.rewardedAd.OnUserEarnedReward += HandleUserEarnedReward;       
        this.rewardedAd.OnAdClosed += HandleRewardedAdClosed;


        AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder().AddTestDevice(SystemInfo.deviceUniqueIdentifier).Build();
        this.rewardedAd.LoadAd(request);
    }

    public void HandleRewardedAdLoaded(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        MonoBehaviour.print("HandleRewardedAdLoaded event received");
    }

    public void HandleRewardedAdFailedToLoad(object sender, AdErrorEventArgs args)
    {
        MonoBehaviour.print(
            "HandleRewardedAdFailedToLoad event received with message: "
                             + args.Message);
    }

    public void HandleRewardedAdOpening(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        MonoBehaviour.print("HandleRewardedAdOpening event received");
    }

    public void HandleRewardedAdFailedToShow(object sender, AdErrorEventArgs args)
    {
        MonoBehaviour.print(
            "HandleRewardedAdFailedToShow event received with message: "
                             + args.Message);
    }

    public void HandleRewardedAdClosed(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder().Build();
        this.rewardedAd.LoadAd(request);
    }

    public void HandleUserEarnedReward(object sender, Reward args)
    {
        //Assets.SaveLoad.CloudManager.Instance.AddDiamonds(20);
    }
    public void showIntestitial()
    {
        if (this.interstitial.IsLoaded())
        {
            this.interstitial.Show();
            this.RequestInterstitial();
        }
    }
    public void ShowReward()
    {
        if (this.rewardedAd.IsLoaded())
        {
            this.rewardedAd.Show();
            this.LoadReward();
        }
    }
    public bool bottom;
    private void RequestBanner()
    {
        if (!bottom)
        {
            return;
           }
#if UNITY_ANDROID
        string adUnitId = "ca-app-pub-2993038425431208/8049796478";        
#elif UNITY_IPHONE
            string adUnitId = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2934735716";
#else
            string adUnitId = "unexpected_platform";
#endif


        this.bannerView = new BannerView(adUnitId, new AdSize(AdSize.FullWidth, 50), AdPosition.Top);


        AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder().AddTestDevice(SystemInfo.deviceUniqueIdentifier).Build();
        this.bannerView.LoadAd(request);
        this.bannerView.Show();

    }
}
```

[The Other App Banner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yRIlv.jpg)
[Te Other App Rewarded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CXVnR.jpg)

Comment: Why are you adding this "AddTestDevice(SystemInfo.deviceUniqueIdentifier)" if you want real ads?

Comment: even with "AddTestDevice(SystemInfo.deviceUniqueIdentifier)" it shows real ads but will avoid ban because this initialization will make the API to not count the clicks etc..

Comment: even if i remove "AddTestDevice(SystemInfo.deviceUniqueIdentifier)" i have the same problem.

Comment: @DeekshithHegde Can this be a problem of GPGS? if so how can i solve it ? I`m not so good with ".jar"s;

Answer (score 0):

I found that the problem is that GPGS and AdMob cannot work together.
I deleted GPGS and AdMob. Reimported AdMob -> Resolute Again  Boom it works, but I can`t make them work together.

Answer (score 0):

your line:

```
AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder().AddTestDevice(SystemInfo.deviceUniqueIdentifier).Build();
```

try this line:

```
AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder().Build();
```

this line worked for me.